# Cannot query AD users in function

Tags: powershell, recursion

Diffictult to explain the question in one sentence.

**The Problem**

I have created a function that should add all users from a group (huge group with 1000's of users) into an array. Everytime the function sees a group it calls itself with that group.

Problem is, the main part and just this line `$tempUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberof=$($myGroup.distinguishedname)))"` doesn't get executed at all.

It just finishes the script after I started it.

**The function**

```
function Get-AllMembersFromGroup {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [Alias()]
  Param
  (
      # Postfach auf dieses Berechtigt werden soll
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                Position=0)]
      [string]
      $Identity
  )

  Begin {
      $users = @()
      $myGroup = Get-ADGroup $Identity
      $tempUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberof=$($myGroup.distinguishedname)))"
  }

  Process {
      foreach($user in $tempUsers) {
          if($user.GetType().Name -eq "ADPrincipal") {
              Get-AllMembersFromGroup -Identity $user
          } else {
              $users += $user
          }
      }
  }

  End {
      #$users.count
  }

}
```

I'm not getting it. I placed several "write-host" statements to what is getting printed and what not. The first line `$myGroup = Get-ADGroup $Identity` gets run and has a ad group inside.

But after then `$tempUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberof=$($myGroup.distinguishedname)))"`  -> `$tempUsers` is just empty.

If I uncomment the last statement `$users.count` it prints `0` immediately after I start the script

When I run the command in a plain powershell:

```
$tempUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberof=$($myGroup.distinguishedname)))"
```

it works and after 10 seconds of waiting time I have 3000 users in this variable, just as I wanted.

What am I doing wrong? Can you find the problem?

Comment: Your code works for me. What Powershell version do you use?

Comment: _Diffictult to explain the question in one sentence._ It would be really bad if you'd try to explain it in one sentence.

Comment: $tempUsers is just empty. Could that be Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter returned nothing?

Comment: Isn't your function pretty much doing what Get-ADGroupMember does?

Comment: Right, just use `Get-ADGroupMember -Recurse`.

Comment: Yes but these group has about 10k nested groups and users so I get a time out with get-adgroupmember.